# LowMemoryHelper is wrong for Lumia 800

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Using classical case

```
public class LowMemoryHelper
{
    public static bool IsLowMemDevice { get; set; }

    static LowMemoryHelper()
    {
        try
        {
            Int64 result = (Int64)DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("ApplicationWorkingSetLimit");
            if (result < 94371840L)
                IsLowMemDevice = true;
            else
                IsLowMemDevice = false;
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        {
            // Windows Phone OS update not installed, which indicates a 512-MB device. 
            IsLowMemDevice = false;
        }
    }
}
```

However, when running on Lumia 800, i got result = 223506432, and IsLowMemDevice = false; I'm totally surprised with this behavior.

Comment: Um, 223506432 is larger than 94371840, so why are you surprised by the result?

Comment: I'm surprised, because Lumia 800 should return result, smaller than 94371840.

Comment: It's been solved now, and was based on a mistaken assumption on the part of the OP - not actually a coding issue.


Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, i used to use Lumia 800 for a long time. I thought it is lowmemory device. However, it has 512 Mb, not 256, so it is not lowmemory.

Comment: Low memory definition here => [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh855081(v=vs.105).aspx)